# Special characters are displayed on the page from database, how to solve it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have page in which data is being fetched and displayed. But few of the characters are displayed as special characters

Likewise: Â , inverted question etc...

I am using mysql db and PHP

Comment: That's a charset problem.
What are your database, database link and produced pages charsets ?

Answer (score 4):

sounds like the charset problem thats been discussed on SO and all over the internet a million times (on SO theres a [search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=special+character+php+mysql) that you should use before asking a question). simply use the same charset *everywhere* (and, if you have to choose, use utf-8). [this](http://akrabat.com/php/utf8-php-and-mysql/) is a very good and short instruction what you'll have to do. basically:

- deliver your site as utf-8 (by setting the correct header)
- use uft-8 for database-connection (`mysql_set_charset('utf8');` or `SET NAMES UTF8;`) (*this* is what most people forget)
- use uft-8 as collation for varchar/text-fields in your DB
- set `accept-charset` to utf-8 on your forms

Answer (score 1):

To help you we will need more details. This is probably a charset problem. Like if your database is in ISO 8859-1 but your webpage is in UTF-8.

Check the charset of your database tables and the charset of your pages.

I will update my answer with more usefull tips when you provide more details.